# What's the best way to account for missing records when performing aggregate queries?

Tags: sql, arduino, questdb

I have a table in QuestDB with IoT sensor data. The usual operation pattern is that sensors write info to a table while they have an active internet connection. This means they are anywhere from a few minutes to a few hours per day or constantly sending me data. When I want to run an aggregate query on top of this, how can I account for missing values?
If I want an average by minute over a 24 hour period, but 4 hours of data is missing, will my results be skewed? For example:

```sql
select avg(tempFahren) from (iot_logger timestamp(ts)) sample by 1m
```

It becomes obvious that I'm skipping directly to the next reported value when graphing so instead of a cyclical pattern, I get a sudden cliff when the sensor comes online again:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fill missing values, there is also the option to use the `FILL` keyword in SAMPLE BY aggregations. There are a few ways you can use this, such as filling by previous value, linear interpolation, or specify a constant:

```sql
select ts, avg(tempFahren) from (iot_logger timestamp(ts)) sample by 1m fill(linear);
```

There are some more examples of how to use this on the [official documentation](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/fill)

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation functions like [`avg()`](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/function/aggregation/#avg) ignore missing data (for example `null` values).

So no, your results will not be skewed if your sensors do not send data for some time.